# How to force disconnection in commons-httpclient?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I use commons-httpclient to send queries to a Web server. The Web server never closes connections, but has a small memory leak associated to the connection context.

I would therefore like to close the persistent connections from time to time (every X queries for example), but I did not find any way to do this. I use the MultiThreadedHTTPConnectionManager

I could use MultiThreadedHTTPConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(very_small_delay), but that's not very reliable: if my Java code has much work to do, then it's possible that no connection is ever idle, because there are always other threads waiting for a free connection.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after executing one method, let's say GET, you can read the responsed HttpStatus number, to decide if a method.releaseConnection() needs to be called.

Or if you know which connection you wanna close, you could try

```
MultiThreadedHTTPConnectionManager
void    releaseConnection(HttpConnection conn)
```

okay, I thought you have some reason that you want to 'kill' a connection. Assume you have the connection, the HttpConnection Object, which you want to close in hand. May this method help?

```
HttpConnection
public void close()

    Closes the socket and streams.
```

Comment: Hi,

calling releaseConnection() puts the connection back in the pool, which is not what I want, as it will stay alive. However, if I don't call releaseConnection(), then the pool will think I still use it, and not create another one, basically leading to a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `method.releaseConnection()`?

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html#Connection_Release

Comment: Yes, which has the correct effect of putting the connection back in the pool where it can be reused for another query.

The additional thing I want is to explicitely kill the connection and forbid its reuse, from time to time (doing the client-side equivalent of settings Apache's max keep-alive requests)

Answer (score 0):

Can you afford to use `SimpleHttpConnectionManager(boolean alwaysClose)`?

```
httpClient.setHttpConnectionManager(new SimpleHttpConnectionManager(true))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I am using `releaseConnections()` still there are connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` state. Is it okay if I add `closeIdleConnections(0)` after `releaseConnections`?

Will this mean even if the connection is sent back to the pool to be used by other clients but is not closed/released then `closeIdleConnections` will close it?